# Unable to get decoded payload of JWT from auth0/express-jwt library

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, auth0, express-jwt

I'm trying to obtain the decoded JWT payload using the `express-jwt` from `auth0` as a middleware in my expressjs application. For the token to be used for authentication, I have to use a custom `async` function to process the token first before providing it to `express-jwt`.  I understand that I can write a custom function under the `getToken` parameter as documented in `express-jwt` as shown below, but it does not work with `async` function.

```
const jwt = require("express-jwt");

const checkJwt = jwt({
  secret: 'hello world !',
  algorithms: ['HS256'],
  credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }
});

module.exports = checkJwt;
```

To overcome this limitation, I included the `jwt()` as part of a larger middleware function that first process the token, and then providing it to `jwt()`. The unprocessed token is attached to my headers. My code structure is as follows:

```
const myMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Process Token First
  const processedToken = await functionToProcessToken(req.headers.tokenLocation);
  // Jwt Authentication
  jwt({
    secret: 'hello world !',
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
    credentialsRequired: false,
    getToken: processedToken
  });
  next();
});

module.exports = myMiddleware;
```

While I'm able to authenticate my routes without any issue, I need to get the decoded JWT payload for further uses. By default, as written in the documentation, the decoded payload should have been attached to `req.user`, but when I try to console.log it, it shows `undefined`.  I have also tried adding `requestProperty` but it does not work as well. The documentation for `resultProperty` is not very clear, so I could not get that to work too.

I very much appreciate if someone can point me towards right direction to help me achieve the expected outcome for my middleware. Thank you!